# Downloading Desktop Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am very new to this so please have patience, but I am trying to download the desktop version of Ubuntu. When I click on download it is doing it's download but it always wants me to burn the download to a disc, but I want it to load to my C# so I can load it to VirtualBox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "C#"?  You can load an ISO into VBox without burning a disk, unless your system is weird.

Answer (score 1):

On the computer VirtualBox is on:

1. Download the ISO to a safe place. Note that you do not want to select "Run With", but instead "Save as..."
   [image]
2. Open VirtualBox.
3. Create a new VM for Ubuntu.
   [image]
4. Enter Settings and go to the Disk menu.
   [image]
5. Under SATA, add a new CD drive.
   [image]
6. Select the ISO
7. Exit out, saving all settings.
8. Boot the VM.
   [image]
9. ???
10. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you mean C drive (C:). When you click download, you need to make sure you save it to your hard drive instead of trying to run it.

Make sure your Computer has the right requirements for Ubuntu before doing this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

For help on creating a virtual machine with Ubuntu, look at the link below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox